# flutter apply or copyWith method

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to apply blue color on `Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6`, it can be done in two ways

```dart
Text(
  "Hello",
  style: Theme.of(context)
      .textTheme
      .headline6!
      .copyWith(color: Colors.blue),
),
```

**or**

```dart
Text(
  "Hello",
  style: Theme.of(context)
      .textTheme
      .headline6!
      .apply(color: Colors.blue),
),
```

Which one you prefer `copyWith` or `apply` method?

[Preview on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7BSV.png)

Comment: Do you figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that `apply()` offers several parameters to **scale** parameters of the source `TextStyle`.

For example, `copyWith(fontSize: 14)` lets you explicitly set the font size, while `apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.6)` lets you *scale* the source's font size **by** a custom factor (note that an explicit `fontSize` parameter does not exist in `apply()`).

Answer (score 0):

`apply()` creates a copy of text style replacing or altering the specified properties in it.

`copyWith()`  creates a copy of text style but with the given fields replaced with the new values.

*source* [Flutter: Apply style as a Theme in a Text widget](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-apply-style-as-a-theme-in-a-text-widget-90268328bd23)

Comment: No sure what it means. Can you explain a little more? Thank you.

Comment: This is TextStyle.(apply/copyWith), not TextTheme.(apply/copyWith)